# How did Zheng He's treasure ships solve the problem of vitamin C supply?

Tags: ming-dynasty

[Scurvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scurvy) was the number one disease that plagued sailors. How did the [Zheng He](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He) [treasure ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_treasure_voyages) prevent scurvy in their sailors?

Comment: I think you meant "scurvy", not "sepsis". And the answer might be "coastal navigation", you need 30-40 days of poor diet to have scurvy.

Comment: Welcome to H:SE! I like the premise of the question (i.e., diet on Zheng He's voyages) but you should demonstrate previous research beyond links to relevant Wiki articles (i.e., is this topic not mentioned there or is the detail insufficient)?

Comment: It takes weeks for scurvy to develop. Zheng He's voyages largely hugged the coast, following well-tread trade routes. Is there reason to believe they'd be short on fresh produce for prolonged periods? Scurvy doesn't seem to be a particularly notable problem for European sailors prior to the long distance voyages on the age of sail either.

Comment: Keep in mind that De Menzies'theories of Zheng He visiting every place in the world (except, curiosly, those places where such a visit would have been well documented) are generally not considered to be serious.

Comment: Haven't tried looking, so I could be way wrong, but I'd be surprised if the sources we have for Zheng He go into that kind of mundane detail.

Comment: Same question on Reddit has a decent answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/4mzlpx/were_zheng_hes_voyages_afflicted_with_scurvy_did/

Comment: I believe years ago, answering a similar question, I found sources claiming that the diet of Chinese landsmen and sailors was much better at preventing scurvy than that of westerners.  I belive it was Avoiding the Die straits: An Inquiry into Food Provisioning and Scurvy in the Maritime and Military History of China and wider East Asia Mathieu Torck, Pages 132-134, 146, 150  - https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34369/were-shipboard-gardens-ever-typical/34383#34383